# Using sum_over_time for a Promql increase function recorded using recording rules

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a use case where I have a recording rule calculating the increase of a counter over `2m` with an evaluation interval of `2m` and I have to aggregate over the rule to find the number of events over a variable period of time. The recording rule looks something like this:

```
  - name: example
    evaluation_interval: 2m
    rules:
      - record: http_requests_total:increase2m
        expr: increase(http_requests_total[2m])
```

I am trying to get the number of events using an expression `sum_over_time(http_requests_total:increase2m[24h])`

Is this approach correct? Are there any edge-cases to consider?

Answer (score 2):

One scenario when I would fail or produce misleading results is:

Imagine that your `http_requests_total` has a data point every minute - for example 30 seconds after a full minute. So at +30s, +90s, +150s etc.
Now the internal timer for your recording rule evaluation starts at 0s.
After two minutes it will run calculating `increase` (at +120s) from data points at +30s and +90s. Next time it will run at +240s, but it will only use data points at +150s and 210s to calculate the increase. Note that actual increase between data points +90s and +150s was not included in any data point in your aggregated metric. Hopefully this will illustrate it better:

```
TIME            | 0s    60s   120s   180s   240s   300s 
scraped         |     *     *      *      *      *  
rec rule called | |------------*
                |               |-------------*
                |                              |--------(...)
```

Prometheus does extrapolate data when running `increase()`, `rate()` and similar function, so in some cases it will be mostly fine.
But if you have small amount of incoming requests it may happen that *the only* increase in value of the `http_total_requests` happened between those "skipped" data points and the aggregated metric will only show zeroes.
This is described in https://www.doit-intl.com/making-peace-with-prometheus-rate/. Not that the problem there is demonstrated using grafana querying prometheus, but you can think of your recording rule as such query.

You didn't mention why are you creating this recording rule in the first place. If the performance will allow it then using `increase` function directly on the `http_requests_total` would be better and would produce more accurate results. If possible let us know about your use case in more detail :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The use case is for SLO aggregation, there are a bunch of SLOs with different underlying metrics and the above rule is used to calculate the number of good and total events that have happened in the current day for each SLO in a single query rather than making multiple queries (one for each SLO) and aggregating over them using operators. I am thinking of adding 1 hour evaluation time with range vector over 1 hour and few minutes. This will have some overlap but will give a better estimate. WDYT?

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus misses some counter increases due to its data model described by @bjakubski . So `sum_over_time(increase(metric[2m])[24h:2m])` doesn't equal to `increase(metric[24h])` in most cases.

This issue has been solved by `increase()` function in MetricsQL though - a query language inspired by PromQL (and mostly backwards-compatible with PromQL) - see [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html).